# Google cloud messaging time to live

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I was developing android application which uses GCM, but I want to cancel message delivery if user phone is not online. Is there any way to decrease time to live value to minimum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer @ http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html

> Another advantage of specifying the expiration date for a message is
>   that GCM will never throttle messages with a time_to_live value of 0
>   seconds. In other words, GCM will guarantee best effort for messages
>   that must be delivered "now or never." Keep in mind that a
>   time_to_live value of 0 means messages that can't be delivered
>   immediately will be discarded. However, because such messages are
>   never stored, this provides the best latency for sending
>   notifications.
>
> Here is an example of a JSON-formatted request that includes TTL:

```
{
  "collapse_key" : "demo",
  "delay_while_idle" : true,
  "registration_ids" : ["xyz"],
  "data" : {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2",
  },
  "time_to_live" : 3
},
```

Comment: Anyway I can put TTL via Curl on PHP?

Comment: Surely you can do this  in any way where you can send HTTP request to the server, this message (JSON) nothing more that simple formatted text.